# Character Input In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, character, gnustep

I'm learning Objective-C using GNUstep, but i searched at Google for some example of character input using Objective-C, like scanf in C and cin at C++, but i didn't found, someone can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything C can do, Objective-C can do.
Anything Objective-C can do, C can do (with some work on your part).

If you find something that works in C, it will work in Objective-C.
If you find something that works in Objective-C, it will work in C (with some work on your part).

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` should work fine in Objective-C.